# how to export Azure Database for MySQL server to blob?

Tags: azure, database, azure-sql

is there a way to export Azure Database for MySQL server to a blob or a container ? my main goal is to keep the backup for over 35 days in blob/container and still be able to restore it after?
i want to be able to save backups in the cloud and with azure tools , `cli/power shell/` job so that i want need to do so on my own in common tools (`mysqldump` etc...)

Answer (score 1):

You have built-in backup in Azure Database for MySQL
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-restore-server-portal

But if you really want export to Azure Storage then I would recommend [Data Factory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/).

Here is some documentation on connection Data factory and Azure MySQL.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-database-for-MySQL

You can then either run it on schedule or trigger it with .Net or Python SKD , REST api or Powershell.